# What are the seal characters on this white jade pendant? (Characters identified: 龍德)

Tags: meaning, character-identification

[image]

What do these Chinese seal characters mean?

Comment: Is there anything on the other side of the pendant?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like 龍德, which seems to be the name of various Chinese and Vietnamese kings.

Comment: Given the poor design of this jade pendant I believe it's just coined by a designer...

Comment: 龍德 is possibly the dynasty represented by 后梁末帝朱友贞 (https://www.wikiwand.com/zh/%E9%BE%99%E5%BE%B7), but it could be anything really.

Comment: @MichaelLai Very good point!